# Flatness over Hopf subalgebra

Tags: hopf-algebras, flatness, group-schemes, dedekind-domains

Let $A\subset B$ be flat Hopf algebras over a Dedekind ring $R$.

J. Moore has proved in the article 
[*Compléments sur les algèbres de Hopf*, John C. Moore, Séminaire Henri Cartan (1959-1960), Volume: 12, Issue: 1, page 1-12](https://eudml.org/doc/112398)
that if $B/A$ is $R$-flat then $B$ is flat over $A$.

This is the contents of Thm 6, which follows from Thm 5. However Thm 5 assumes that $A\subset B$ are graded algebras over $R$. How can one make a Hopf algebra graded algebra?

Comment: I don't undertand what you are asking.

Comment: If I understand the question, just view an ungraded Hopf algebra as a graded Hopf algebra concentrated in degree zero.

Comment: I apologize for not having explained in detail. In fact, in the cited paper, Moore defined a graded algebra as a "connected graded algebra", that is, its 0-th component is exactly R. Thus, one cannot view an arbitrary Hopf algebra as a graded one (concentrated in degree 0). Also the definition of Hopf algebra in that paper differs from the now commonly accepted definition of Hopf algebras. In Moore's definition, a Hopf algebra is just a bialgebra. Thus it seems that Moore considered in that paper only bialgebras, which, as an algebra is connected graded. Moore's theorem mentioned above has ...

Comment: ... therefore less connection with the well-known faithful flatness theorem for commutative Hopf algebras over fields (a Hopf algebra is faithfully flat over a Hopf subalgebra).